# что значит c++(номер)?

Tags: c++

я копался в своем ide и нашел какие-то надписи:C++20 C++11 и тп, что это значит?
еще на сайте cppreference я видел это, можете объяснить что это?
[image: вот оно]

Comment: Считай что это версия языка

Comment: since XXXX — начиная с XXXX

Comment: Это ссылка на стандарт и версию реализации. Т.е. эта форма записи не будет работать в стандарте ниже 17. Но с 17 и выше будет.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: @FrancNet Не на версию реализации. Про 17 не понял - что до него было по-другому?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ну вот к примеру в Си, до стандарта 99 работать с структурами можно было только так.  struct name{}; В стандарте 99 появилась возможность typedef struct name{} MyData; и потом писать просто MyData var; Я думаю если в поиске набрать стандарты C или C++ и там будет подробная инфа ;)

Comment: @FrancNet Извиняюсь, не тем местом вторую половину коммента прочитал, теперь долшло. Но для справедливости, это не в C99 добавили: оно работает даже в C89: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/h5sfdhf5Y (но это если добавить хотя бы один член в структуру, без него и C99 не берет).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ну как и в Си, так и в Си++ вносили изменения в синтаксис. Я его не читал, смотрел видео о разных стандартах и что нового. И там было (вроде) именно с 99 это изменение. Т.к. я заколебывался везде писать struct :) И во многих книгах и видеообучениях говорят что многие работают в 99 стандарте Си, типа он самый оптимальный, по логике написания и размеру исходника :)

Answer (score 4):

Это версия (стандарт) языка. Чем больше число (кроме 98) тем новее релиз. "since" в переводе с английского ознчает "с". Т.е. "since C++17" означает доступно с 17 версии C++. В данном случае 17 означает 2017 год, 98 -> 1998, 11 -> 2011, и т.д.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Да, верно подмечено!

Answer (score 3):

Это версия языка, цифра означает год публикации: `98`, `03`, `11`, `14`, `17`, `20`, `23`, следующая должна быть `26`.

Еще не вышедшую версию иногда пишут с буквой-заглушкой вместо цифры, вместо того чтобы пытаться угадать год. Когда версия выходит, букву меняют на правильную цифру:
`0x -> 1x -> 11` (тут даже с первой цифрой сначала не угадали), `1y -> 14`, `1z -> 17`, `2a -> 20`, `2b -> 23`, `2c -> ??` (вероятно 26).

Обратите внимание, это не то же самое, что версия конкретного компилятора. У каждого компилятора своя нумерация версий, а эти цифры - версия единого стандарта (документа), котому компиляторы стараются следовать.

У компиляторов есть флаги командной строки, которыми можно выбрать версию языка. Обычно они сохраняют поддержку и старых версий тоже.

Comment: а почему следующая должна быть 26, а не 24? по идее должен же быть 24 год. Во вторых где можно посмотреть нововведения в стандартах ? хочу посмотреть какие-то новые классные фишки любимого языка

Comment: @MikeNovi Они не каждый год выходят, а где-то каждые три года сейчас. Попробуйте погуглить статьи в духе "нововведения в C++17" (или какая версия вас интересует). Или вот тут есть подробный список: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support